# 'Not a valid key' error from sbt-release build command

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-release

I installed the `sbt-release` plugin in my scala sbt project.

But when I run *sbt release cross build* or *sbt release skip-tests*, I get this error:

```
Not a valid key: cross (similar: crossPaths, crossTarget, cross-paths)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run `release cross with-defaults` or `release skip-tests` from the command line you need to quote it:

```
$ sbt 'release cross with-defaults'

$ sbt 'release skip-tests'
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, so following up question, can we set a version to release? like, sbt 'release 0.1.7', I know this grammar is wrong, but I don't know whether  sbt release support assigning a version ourself or not.

Comment: One options is `with-defaults`, as described in the README: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release#non-interactive-release

Comment: But how to give the version, with-defaults will use the version suggested by sbt itself.  and I tried 'sbt 'release with-defaults 0.1.7'  ', but it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the release plugin doesn't play nice when you run it this way.
Try running sbt, then run release from within the console.